# No Apache2 response after File response via PHP

Tags: php, apache

With Symfony2/PHP, I'm returning a file content (its size can reach 10Mo).

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=file.pdf');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Expires', 0);
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
$response->headers->set('Content-Length', $file->getSize());
$response->setContent($file->getContent());

return $response;
```

It works fine with one file, but the user can several files at once. 
And randomly, after x download attempts, the server is not responding at all to the client for a while. If I try with another browser, it works again. And other users are not impacted.

I tried several Apache2 configuration, but it changes nothing. Here is the current configuration.

```
Timeout 30
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

# MPM Module
StartServers              10
MinSpareServers           5
MaxSpareServers           20
MaxRequestWorkers         250
MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
```

I don't know where to look now... Any idea? Thanks!